# How to filter an array to form another array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I apologize for poorly describing the title, Here is the problem am facing I have this array.

```
data=[
      {name: "jhon", subject:"bio", total:40},
      {name: "jhon", subject:"chem", total:80},
      {name: "jhon", subject:"geo", total:50},
      {name: "jhon", subject:"art", total:100},
      {name: "jane", subject:"bio", total:40},
      {name: "jane", subject:"chem", total:80},
      {name: "jane", subject:"geo", total:50},
      {name: "jane", subject:"art", total:100}
      ]
```

and I want to filter it so that I get this array and am using php,

```
result=[
        {name: "jhon", bio:40, chem:80, geo:50,art:100},
        {name: "jane", bio:40, chem:80, geo:50,art:100}
       ]
```

Comment: Decode the json, and use `array_filter`

Comment: How do I do that? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show your own efforts.

Comment: _“How do I do that?”_ - you start by doing some research / reading-up on how the mentioned function works, and then you try something. If you don’t succeed, then you report back here, with a proper problem description ([ask]) and [mre] of what you did.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
$data = '[
      {"name":"jhon","subject":"bio","total":40},
      {"name":"jhon","subject":"chem","total":80},
      {"name":"jhon","subject":"geo","total":50},
      {"name":"jhon","subject":"art","total":100},
      {"name":"jane","subject":"bio","total":40},
      {"name":"jane","subject":"chem","total":80},
      {"name":"jane","subject":"geo","total":50},
      {"name":"jane","subject":"art","total":100}
      ]';

// Setting the second parameter to `true` means it decodes to an
// associative array...
$array = json_decode($data, true);

// Initialise the transformation array (empty array)
$transformArray = [];

foreach($array as $item){
    $transformArray[$item["name"]]["name"]           = $item["name"];
    $transformArray[$item["name"]][$item["subject"]] = $item["total"];
}

// Re-index the array to numeric and convert to JSON string
$output = json_encode( array_values($transformArray) );

echo $output;
```

Output:

```
[
    {"name":"jhon","bio":40,"chem":80,"geo":50,"art":100}, 
    {"name":"jane","bio":40,"chem":80,"geo":50,"art":100}
]
```

Comment: Nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This is also very easy if you use a special PHP class.

```
require 'class/tableArray.php';
//https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray

$jsonData = '[
      {"name": "jhon", "subject":"bio", "total":40},
      {"name": "jhon", "subject":"chem", "total":80},
      {"name": "jhon", "subject":"geo", "total":50},
      {"name": "jhon", "subject":"art", "total":100},
      {"name": "jane", "subject":"bio", "total":40},
      {"name": "jane", "subject":"chem", "total":80},
      {"name": "jane", "subject":"geo", "total":50},
      {"name": "jane", "subject":"art", "total":100}
      ]';

$newJson = tableArray::createFromJson($jsonData)
  ->pivot('name','total','subject')
  ->fetchAllAsJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)
;

//test output
echo '<pre>';
echo $newJson;
```

Different keys are used in the result than requested in the question. I think these keys are more understandable and convenient to access the values by name.

```
{
    "jhon": {
        "name": "jhon",
        "total.bio": 40,
        "total.chem": 80,
        "total.geo": 50,
        "total.art": 100
    },
    "jane": {
        "name": "jane",
        "total.bio": 40,
        "total.chem": 80,
        "total.geo": 50,
        "total.art": 100
    }
}
```